# Timeout during Webhook subscription verification

Tags: facebook, webhooks, real-time-updates

I am trying to use Facebook Webhooks/Real Time Updates.
When subscribing, the verification request fails with the following message:

> (#2200) callback verification failed: Operation timed out after 6001 milliseconds with 0 bytes received

which seems normal to me, because my application has not completed its initialization yet.

After a few seconds, I receive another verification call on my callback URL that is confirmed by my application.

However, my subscription is not registered (`GET {app-id}/subscriptions` returns an empty array).

When I try to subscribe after my application is fully initialized, the verification request succeeds on the first try and my subscription appears when `GET {app-id}/subscriptions`.

I had no problem with previous versions of Facebook API. With API v2.3, there was a timeout on the first verification call, but the second was successful and the subscriptions were registered.
Is is a intentional change of behaviour?

Comment: It's not clear to me why you don't trigger the subscription **after** your application has started...

Comment: If your app doesn’t manage to complete its “initialization” in under six seconds, then that’s something you should fix.

Comment: I was just wondering why my subscription was not registered when the verification fails first and then succeeds. It seems to be a retry, but it is not creating a new subscription and it looked like a bug to me.